# Should we sanitise and clean data or only display it in the expected format?

Tags: mvc, database-design, database-development

So my problem is, I have users entering their data(names, address) in a mixed form- some with first letter in caps and some without, some inserting more than necessary spaces and so forth.

Also, since there are some with titles in their names(happens in some parts of Europe), the title words have to be in small. 
Now the obvious thing to do is remove spaces and capitalize all the data in the model and then insert/update to the db.

My question: Is this the right thing to do? Or should I store the data as it was entered and only make it look right with view side functionality?
 what do large systems like ERP and CRM systems do?

Comment: It really depends on what your client and its users want.

Comment: @MetaFight , They are not sure about it.. They just want the letters capitalised where it should be, irrespective of how users are entering it.

Comment: Well, it sounds like they actually do know what they want "They just want the letters capitalised where it should be, irrespective of how users are entering it".  Next is to figure out what "where it should be" means.  I suspect that if you ask them they won't know, and if you tell them the effort (cost) required to find out they'll say it's not that important.

Comment: Required reading: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my problem is, I have users entering their data(names, address) in a mixed form- some with first letter in caps and some without, some inserting more than necessary spaces and so forth.

To reduce this "noise", redesign your UI to capture this data in a more "structured" form, i.e. separate fields for Title, Forename(s) , Surname. 
However, bear *these* thoughts in mind: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

> should I store the data as it was entered ...

It depends.

If someone enters their name on your site as "suSan", does it matter? 
Not really.  If that's what they want, then why shouldn't they?

Does it matter to your application?  It *shouldn't*, because you should *never* use Names as identifiers (see link, above).

> ... and only make it look right with view side functionality?

No.  Render what was stored.  It's quicker and easier and doesn't "mask" problems that the User might very easily spot (and, potentially, correct) themselves.

You should, of course, *clean* that data on its way "in": http://xkcd.com/327/.
Once the data's "in there", it should be Trustworthy.

Comment: Bobby tables is not a good example for data that should be cleaned on the way in. It should be encoded when you pass it to the db query (or better yet, use parameterized queries).

Answer (score 2):

I would not go too far in determining how people should spell their own name.  There is probable more variation in names in the world than you can capture with your automated rules.

I know someone named "d'Agano" and he is not amused if you 'correct' his name by capitalizing the 'D', remove the apostrophe or lowercase the 'A'.

There are scores of people with 'interesting' names with accents and apostrophes because their parents want them to look special. I have an opinion about that, but the fact is that this really is the spelling of their name.

Suggestions:
- suggest a corrected version on input, while still allowing them their own spelling. "Do you want us to store your name as "Abalone", yes/no ? "

- Cleanup double spaces and remove spaces at start and end of the name. These are harmless.
- Limit the number of different fields for the name.  Maybe just "name" or "first" and "last" name.  But if you ask the user to divide their name over boxes like 'middle name': Why?  You're only reconstructing it anyway. With just First and Last name you can (1) find the person, (2) address a person both formal and informally. Keep it simple.
- invest in a strong search algorithm that finds people even when they've spelled their name a little different.